# hiding an element inside a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, element, visible

I'm trying to hide an anchor inside my ListView by using `visible='false'` , but I have noticed that it is not working. I have also tried hiding the element using css but it's also not working. I have checked and there are no javascript errors or code behind errors.

This is what I did:

```
       //inside ItemTemplate in ListView
    <td>
    <a runat="server"  id="selectionAnchor" href='Somelocation' visible='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(uoshowHiddenField.Value)) %>' >  Edit</a>
 </td>
```

I placed my uoShowHiddenField above the listview :

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="uoShowHiddenField" runat="server" Value="false" />
```

but whenever I inspect the element in the browser it shows up like this:

```
<a href="Somelocation" id="selectionAnchor"> Edit</a>
```

I have also tried using this method to no avail:

```
style=' <%# (uoShowHiddenField.Value == "true") %> ? " ": "display:none;" %> '
```

Am I doing something wrong? It has taken alot of my time and I am really frustrated as to why it's not working.

Comment: @adaam I tried changing # to = using the visible= method but it produces an error "Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation"

Comment: Have you tried using ItemDataBound instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)? Have you looked at the value of uoShowHiddenField using the debugger?

Comment: @adaam yes I have checked the value of uoShowHiddenField using the debugger,but I might take a look at what you said regarding the ItemDataBound

Comment: It's a lot easier to use. I'll post a rough answer demonstrating it. Is the hidden field outside of the listview? So if the value of the hdn field is false, the hyperlink is hidden for all items in the list view?

Comment: @adaam yes the hidden field is outside the listview. Would that affect the process?

Comment: yes it would. If you had a hidden field inside of the item template, that would mean you would have multiple hidden fields (depending on no. of items in listview) so you would need to target the hidden field from within the `OnItemDataBound` handler by using `HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("theHiddenID")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very rough rundown, but this is how you would do it. Remember to include the `OnItemDataBound=""` event binding to the ListView in the .aspx code:

**Code behind:**

As you are using a plain old HTML hyperlink, you will have to use the `HtmlGenericControl` class to target the control

```
protected void SampleListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
       if(uoShowHiddenField.Value == "true") {
          HtmlGenericControl hyperlink = (HtmlGenericControl)e.item.FindControl("selectionAnchor");
          hyperlink.Visible = false;
       }
    }
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="SampleListView" OnItemDataBound="SampleListView_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a runat="server" ID="selectionAnchor">Link</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

I tend to go for `ItemDataBound` as it aids separation of concerns and reinforces the whole code behind / client code rule.